# Cannot install RabbitMQ UI plugin in fresh install

Tags: plugins, rabbitmq

I am trying to install RabbitMQ Management plugin in a fully fresh install of Erlang and RabbitMQ in Windows 7. I have installed Rabbit MQ. I can verify that the windows service is running. When trying to install the Management plugin I get this error:

```
C:\Program Files\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-3.6.12\sbin>rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq-management
```

2017-09-17 13:07:35 std_error           "File operation error: eio. Target: C:\PROGRA~1\RABBIT~1\RABBIT~1.12\sbin\C:\PRO
GRA~1\RABBIT~1\RABBIT~1.12\sbin\R8260~1. Function: list_dir. Process: code_server."
2017-09-17 13:07:35 std_error           "File operation error: eio. Target: C:\PROGRA~1\RABBIT~1\RABBIT~1.12\sbin\C:\PRO
GRA~1\RABBIT~1\RABBIT~1.12\sbin\C:\PROGRA~1\RABBIT~1\RABBIT~1.12\sbin\R8260~1. Function: list_dir. Process: code_server.
"

=ERROR REPORT==== 17-Sep-2017::23:07:35 ===
File operation error: eio. Target: C:\PROGRA~1\RABBIT~1\RABBIT~1.12\sbin\C:\PROGRA~1\RABBIT~1\RABBIT~1.12\sbin\R8260~1.
Function: list_dir. Process: code_server.

=ERROR REPORT==== 17-Sep-2017::23:07:35 ===
File operation error: eio. Target: C:\PROGRA~1\RABBIT~1\RABBIT~1.12\sbin\C:\PROGRA~1\RABBIT~1\RABBIT~1.12\sbin\C:\PROGRA
~1\RABBIT~1\RABBIT~1.12\sbin\R8260~1. Function: list_dir. Process: code_server.
{"init terminating in do_boot",{undef,[{rabbit_nodes_common,ensure_epmd,[],[]},{rabbit_cli,start_distribution,0,[{file,"
src/rabbit_cli.erl"},{line,160}]},{rabbit_cli,ensure_cli_distribution,0,[{file,"src/rabbit_cli.erl"},{line,54}]},{rabbit
_cli,main,3,[{file,"src/rabbit_cli.erl"},{line,67}]},{init,start_em,1,[{file,"init.erl"},{line,1076}]},{init,do_boot,3,[
{file,"init.erl"},{line,784}]}]}}
init terminating in do_boot ()

That is the message I am getting. I am new to Erlang and it doesn't makes sense at all.

Any input will be appreciated.

Ta

Answer (score 1):

ok, got over this.

- Uninstalled RabbitMQ
- Deleted the files in the C:\Users\rahman\AppData\Roaming\RabbitMQ folder
- Reinstalled RabbitMQ

Also, the other issue was that Rabbit_Home was not set in the environment variables. After setting that to RabbitMQ installation then the above command worked.